# Multiple 2D histogram on same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, histogram2d

I have this script to extract data from an image and roi. I have everything working perfectly except the end when I output the graphs. Basically I'm having trouble with the windowing of both histograms. It doesn't matter if I change the gridsize, mincount, figure size, or x and y limits one of the histograms will always be slightly stretched. When I plot them individually they aren't stretched. Is there a way to make the hexagons on the same plot a consistent "non-stretched" shape?
Down below is my graph and plotting methods. (I left out my data extraction methods because it was quite specialized).

```
plt.ion()
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('2D Histogram of Entorhinal Cortex ROIs')
plt.xlabel(x_inputs) 
plt.ylabel(y_inputs)
colors = ['Reds','Blues']
x = []
y= []
#image extraction code
hist1 = plt.hexbin(x[0],y[0], gridsize=100,cmap='Reds',mincnt=10, alpha=0.35)
hist2 = plt.hexbin(x[1],y[1], gridsize=100,cmap='Blues',mincnt=10, alpha=0.35)
plt.colorbar(hist1, orientation="vertical")
plt.colorbar(hist2, orientation="vertical")
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwij7.png)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by setting limits for the bins with the [`extent`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) parameter. This can be done automatically by computing the minimum and maximum x and y values across all the data being plotted. In cases where `gridsize` is small (e.g. 10), this approach may result in some of the bins being partially outside of the plot limits. If so, setting a margin with [`plt.margins`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) can help display all the bins within the plot.

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.20.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4

# Create a random dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123) # random number generator
size = 10000
x1 = rng.normal(loc=5, scale=10, size=size)
y1 = rng.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=size)
x2 = rng.normal(loc=-30, scale=5, size=size)
y2 = rng.normal(loc=-20, scale=5, size=size)

# Define hexbin grid extent
xmin = min(*x1, *x2)
xmax = max(*x1, *x2)
ymin = min(*y1, *y2)
ymax = max(*y1, *y2)
ext = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# Draw figure with colorbars
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
hist1 = plt.hexbin(x1, y1, gridsize=30, cmap='Reds', mincnt=10, alpha=0.3, extent=ext)
hist2 = plt.hexbin(x2, y2, gridsize=30, cmap='Blues', mincnt=10, alpha=0.3, extent=ext)
plt.colorbar(hist1, orientation='vertical')
plt.colorbar(hist2, orientation='vertical')
# plt.margins(0.1) # Uncomment this if hex bins are partially outside of plot limits

plt.show()
```

[image: hexbin]